# Create gitignore for flask application

Tags: git, flask

What the files I need add to `.gitignore` in Flask application?
https://www.gitignore.io/ - I'm usually here to look at examples.
But now I found no examples.
Why? Is it a feature of Flask?
Django has a clear structure in the application, but Flask not have, am I right?

Comment: `git` has nothing to do with Flask. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [Python.gitignore](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Python.gitignore). Flask is a Python project.

Answer (score 8):

Initially, I'd say you will want to include the `/__pycache__/` folders in your `.gitignore` file.

But anything else you may wish to have ignored is incredibly project dependant. It depends on what your Flask app is doing.

You need to ask yourself what exactly your project is doing. Is it storing lists of user details (such as usernames / passwords) somewhere? Then you'll want to keep those details out of `git`. Are you accessing a database with a user and password and showing how to access confidential information in your database tables? Then you should be making sure none of those end up in a public `git` repository where just anyone can waltz on in and see how everything you've built has been put together and where they need to go to access all sensitive data stored by your app.

Depending on your goal with your app, maybe you could consider using a private repository?

Without further information on your Flask application, I can't say much more. But this is my response to the matter either way.

Definitely ignore the `/__pycache__/` folders generated by Python. After that? It's entirely down to the requirements of your app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [gitignore.io](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore), which selects the files to ignore based on the technologies you are using in your project. There are a few of them only for flask.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31474044)

Answer (score 0):

Including
`/__pycache__/` in .gitignore file is good practice like adding
`node_modules` in case of javascript or its frameworks.